# SQL increment value with values variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this SQL Server procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddBagTab]
    @LotNumber nvarchar(15),
    @CounterPart nvarchar(7)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ile INT

    SELECT @ile = COUNT(*) 
    FROM PrinterArchive 
    WHERE LotNumber = @LotNumber 
      AND CounterPart = @CounterPart
    
    IF @ile = 0
        INSERT INTO PrinterArchive(LotNumber, CounterPart, DataInsert)
        VALUES (@LotNumber, @CounterPart, GETDATE())
    ELSE
        PRINT 'Taki worek już istnieje'
END
```

I need it to insert into a table with three columns.

It should insert records according to:

```
LotNumber: CounterPart
272181121032: 00001
272181121032: 00002
272181121032: 00003
etc.
```

The `CounterPart` value is set in the variable field as 00001 and depends on the value of the field in another variable, i.e. if I choose a batch and enter 10 in the application column, it should increase the values from 00001 to 00010 for me and at the next calculation it should increase from 00011.

I don't know how I can achieve it in the procedure, what to modify?

Comment: Why use a `COUNT` to check if the row already exists and not just use a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`/`INDEX`?

Comment: he value in CounterPart cannot repeat itself.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Use an `IDENTITY` column, plus another `BatchID` column, don't combine multiple pieces of info

Comment: *"e value in CounterPart cannot repeat itself."* So, again, why not use a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`/`INDEX`?